# How to start a fresh instance during local VS Code extension development?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a standard VS Code extension development project- I started from the official docs [Your First Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension#developing-the-extension).

Things are working fine, but now I need to clear the stored secrets, before launching the extension host. Is there a working dir I can specify during launch, or, clear all locally stored data and launch it again?

My `launch.json` for ref:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test/suite/index"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
    ]
}
```